# Sharing sqlite database between two different application in Windows

Tags: c#, database, windows, sqlite, visual-c++

I have two desktop applications in Windows, which are written in two different languages: One in VC++ and the other one in C#. We need to make our database common between the two application. How can we make a common folder to consume the same database?

How do we share the path of the database between these two application?

Comment: Shared lock - https://www.sqlite.org/lockingv3.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQLite itself has no access restrictions, and handles locking from multiple processes just fine.

You only have to ensure that both applications have access to the same folder.
The easiest way to do this would be to create a directory in the user's application data folder (e.g., `%APPDATA%\MyLittleCompany\SharedDB\data.sqlite`).

Comment: Thanks it helped. :)